# How to push to another repo for multiple branches from master

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Please see following code:

```
  - name: Checkout the dist repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      repository: xxx/xxx-dist
      path: dist
      ssh-key: ${{ secrets.DIST_KEY }}
      ref: ${{ github.ref }}

  - name: Commit and push the changes to the dist repo
    run: |
      rsync -v -r --delete --exclude=.git/ src/shopify/ dist/

      cd src
      commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
      cd ../dist

      git config user.name github-actions
      git config user.email github-actions@github.com
      
      git add .
      git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "Built $commit"

      git push origin ${{ github.ref }}

      # Sync changes to other dist branches when pushed from master
      ....
```

When pushing from master, above commands sync compiled code to another (dist) repo. The same happens for when I push from dev, or whatever branch. It's always branch x to branch x on dist, branch y to branch y on dist.

I want to accomplish that when pushed from master, not only the master branch continues to get synced but also other (specifically defined) branches:

origin repo master branch push -> execute existing actions = compile + rsync to master on dist **and** rsync to branch y & z on dist. Those already live in the dist repo.